# Hide network shared folder contents from users view

Tags: windows, windows-xp, network-shares

I have this folder which i need to share it out on the network to facilitate patching from another pc but yet i want to prevent users from viewing the contents of the folder, is there any solutions for this?

if i hide the folder and share it out on the network, i realized that when the user do a //192.168.x.x/ from another pc , the folder contents will still be visible even if its hidden.
What i wanted to achieve is that the user will be able to access folder thru the network but not able to see any files within the folder (meaning he shd see a empty folder). Is it possible???

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [Access Based Enumeration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for Windows Server. I believe it is still possible for Windows Professional workgroups to accomplish the same thing using [advanced ntfs permissions](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that what you're asking is possible. You want the files to be accessible in some manner, but not able to be viewed by the end user if I'm interpreting your question correctly.

At a basic level, if you want a folder and its contents to be usable, you're going to need at least READ permission, which would make the files/folders viewable by any user or group you assign that permission to.

The only exception I can think of would be if you're using an Active Directory domain and you configure the security on the share to give the *computer account* read access. The service accessing the share would then also need to be configured to access the share using the AD computer account.

Using Access Based Enumeration as another answer suggests would certainly hide all files and folders within that share that the user *doesn't* have permissions to, but the items that the user *does* have read permission to would still be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden share

To create a hidden share, follow these steps:

1. In Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Computer Management.
2. Expand Shared Folders, right-click Shares, and then click New File Share.
3. In the Folder to share box, type the path of the folder that you want to share, or click Browse to locate the folder.
4. Type the share name that you want to use followed by a dollar sign, and then click Next.
5. To make the share accessible to administrators only, select the Administrators have full control; other users have no access check box, and then click Finish.
6. Click Yes to create another share, or click No to return to the Computer Management console.

Now in order to access this share you have to be an Administrator.  To access it, you will either have to enter admin credentials, or map to with admin credentials.